# Not showing Dolphin's Image Thumbnails on Xubuntu 17.04

Tags: xubuntu, 17.04, dolphin, thumbnails

This is a freshly installed Xubuntu 17.04, since Thunar don't let me do some things I installed Dolphin but it is not showing thumbnails of pictures. Other help on internet is about KDE. What can I do?
Apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Dolphin is part of KDE and works better in its own desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Only install:

```
sudo apt-get install kffmpegthumbnailer
```

Video tutorial in Youtube

[Activar vista previa de videos en Administrador de Archivos dolphin4 en Ubuntu 17.04](https://youtu.be/6A9CPk_YNj8)